# PrimeFaces organigram without lines

Tags: css, primefaces

I need to show Primefaces Organigram component without connectors. I think that the key is CSS style, but I don't know which. Can you help me?

Comment: Effectively client-side it is all plain html and css. Use a browser developer tool and inspect it, learn css, play with it in the browser developer tool and you've got your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should remove all connectors:

```css
.ui-organigram .line {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

Be aware that this removes connectors from *all* organigrams. Adjust the selector to target specific ones.